# Error configuring pipeline debugger in Eclipse

Tags: class, demandware, salesforce-commerce-cloud

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9RGp.png)I have been trying really hard to configure a pipeline debugger in eclipse. After using my digital server account in server configuration when i select my site and click 'Debug' button it gives me an error

```
Could not initialize class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter
```

I couldn't find much help online. I even tried changing the JRE version to an older version 14.0.2 but it doesn't seem to help.

[![Image attached of error][2]][2]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9RGp.png)

Comment: Without knowing your "New_configuration" launch configuration, it's hard to help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example please.

Comment: Hey @howlger, i have updated the attached picture for your reference. As soon as i try to select a site that i want to debug i get this error. The error detail shows its a "treeMapConverter" class error. Please let me know if you need any extra details

Comment: According to the screenshot, it is a _UX Studio: Pipeline debug_ launch/debug configuration, which is something you have installed into your Eclipse and which I do not know. Is this the Salesforce plugin: https://documentation-ja.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/LegacyDevDoc/Debugging.html

Comment: Yes you are right. I followed the steps mentioned in the doc but in my case it gave me the above error mentioned in my question

Answer (score 0):

That library seems to be a core component of the Pipeline editor. I would suggest that you ensure that your Eclipse version is compatible with the plugin if you haven't done so already.

Currently, [according to the documentation](https://documentation-ja.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2FLegacyDevDoc%2FDebugging.html) it only supports:

- Mars - Eclipse 4.5
- Neon - Eclipse 4.6

Furthermore, you *must* install the correct version of the plugin for your version of Eclipse. (Though in the past I've found that older plugin versions *may* sometimes work in newer Eclipse builds.)

Answer (score 0):

This error relates to discounted class from JRE.

So my recipe for solving the issue:

- used OpenJDK v11
- installed latest eclipce version
- SFCC plugin v4.6

Some found issues:

- with new eclipce version brakepoints are not set from JS editor only via ScriptEditor

Thank you,
Aleksandr

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with running debugger, but after I installed eclipse version 2020-12 and installed UX studio plugin it started to work. maybe new versions are not compatible with plugin